# How should you use .PHONY in included Makefiles?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say I have a set of Makefile modules:

```
# foo.mk

rule1: prereq1
    recipe1
```

and

```
# bar.mk

rule2: prereq2
    recipe2
```

and a primary Makefile:

```
# Makefile

include foo.mk
include bar.mk
```

Should `.PHONY:` be included in each individual .mk file for the phony targets just in that file, or should there be some acculmulated list that is included only in the primary Makefile?

```
# foo.mk
TARGETS += rule1
...
# bar.mk
TARGETS += rule2
...
# Makefile
.PHONY: $(TARGETS)
```

I didn't find anything relevant in the [GNU Make docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) or similar questions.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "should".  Either way works fine so do whichever one you prefer.

Comment: "Should" ... as in, is there a best practice or documented & defined way to do something. I don't want to put .PHONY in each file declaring the relevant targets if it's overridden the next time it's encountered.

Comment: `.PHONY` is never overridden.  Like any other target, each new `.PHONY` definition _adds_ more prerequisites to the existing list.  No, there is no best practice that I'm aware of.  Both work identically (except one has a variable defined, which might be useful for other things besides `.PHONY`, and one doesn't).  For the same reason there's no need for a "documented & defined" method.  Whichever one you like better, you should use.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
.PHONY: rule1
```

tells Make that it should not consider "rule1" the name of a file to be built. Suppose you put it in the `Makefile`. What happens when you run another makefile, either `foo.mk` or a makefile that includes it?

When you run the `rule1` rule, do you want Make to treat it as a PHONY target? If your answer isn't *"that depends on which makefile I'm using",* then you should have the statement in the makefile that defines the rule.

Comment: OK, thank you. basically. the .mk modules would never be directly called, but they would be (potentially) included in different "main" Makefiles that would be called. I didn't know if the .PHONY was local to that file or if each time it's encountered in a newly included module the newest statement overrides the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

As with other targets, you can add to `.PHONY` multiple times cumulatively. So giving each file its own `.PHONY` is can be a nice way of keeping things compartmentalized.